# How to use subtotal function with referencing in vba

Tags: excel, vba, date, dynamic, subtotal

I'm trying to apply the subtotal function to a dynamic range. However, I'm unsure of how I should code it since the original function references the sheet and the sheet name has a changing date every week.

This is my vba code:

```
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(last_row + 2, 47) = "=SUBTOTAL(9,AU3:AU" & last_row & ")"
```

The original function is : `=SUBTOTAL(9,'SYS 28.10.2020'!AU3:AU196)`

I have a code for the sheet with changing name but I don't know how to encode it into the function

`szSYS = "SYS"`
`szToday = Format(Date, "D.MM.YYYY")`
`ActiveSheet.Name = szSYS + " " + szToday`

Comment: Can you derive the expected date from week number or current date for example? Or loop sheet until a sheet containing a specific substring e.g. date format "DD.MM.YYYY", or starting with "SYS " etc is found? You would then take that sheet name and concatenate into your VBA.

Comment: Could you reference it by position rather than sheet name? https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-to-referencing-excel-worksheet-tabs